# TypeError: QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolygonXY(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

When I modify the code (which works) from:

```
vertices = fProject.geometry().asMultiPolygon()
for v in vertices:
    points.append(v)
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolygonXY(points))
```

to:

```
pt = QgsPointXY(92.5,22.5)
points.append(pt)
pt = QgsPointXY(93.5,22.5)
points.append(pt)
pt = QgsPointXY(93.5,23.5)
points.append(pt)
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolygonXY(points))
```

throws an error: `TypeError: QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolygonXY(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'`

Comment: Where does `vertices` come from? What's the type of v in the loop `for v in vertices`?

Comment: vertices = fProject.geometry().asMultiPolygon() @MatthiasKuhn

Answer (score 3):

Replace the last line of your code with the last line of the following code.

```
fet = QgsFeature()
pt = QgsPointXY(92.5,22.5)
points.append(pt)
pt = QgsPointXY(93.5,22.5)
points.append(pt)
pt = QgsPointXY(93.5,23.5)
points.append(pt)
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolygonXY([[points]]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vincent Bré. The code worked :)

Comment: You're welcome ! You can approve my answer if it's solved your problem. Have a nice day.